# Selenium webdriver(Maven)-Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died

Tags: java, maven, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've create a sample of gmail login maven project in selenium webdriver but when I am executing project through maven test it display the error for communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
Can anyone please help me to resolving it?

**Error log:**

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running TestSuite
Tests run: 2, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 1, Time elapsed: 64.047 sec <<< FAILURE! - in TestSuite
setUp(GmailLogin.LoginTest)  Time elapsed: 63.593 sec  <<< FAILURE!
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: 
Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '5017cb8e7ca8e37638dc3091b2440b90a1d8686f', time: '2015-02-27 09:10:26'
System info: host: 'SIPL157', ip: '10.10.101.157', os.name: 'Windows 8', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.2', java.version: '1.7.0_51'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
    at GmailLogin.LoginTest.setUp(LoginTest.java:27)
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to 127.0.0.1:7055 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: connect
    at GmailLogin.LoginTest.setUp(LoginTest.java:27)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at GmailLogin.LoginTest.setUp(LoginTest.java:27)
```

**Code:**

```
public class LoginTest {
    private static final String BROWSER_PATH = "E:\\cn\\setup\\FFinstalled\\firefox.exe";
    private static final String ADDRESS_TO_TEST = "https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&passive=true&rm=false&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/&ss=1&scc=1&ltmpl=default&ltmplcache=2&emr=1&osid=1";
    WebDriver driver;
    Main Login;
    HomePage homePage;

    @BeforeTest
    public void setUp() {
        File file = new File(BROWSER_PATH);
        FirefoxBinary fb = new FirefoxBinary(file);
        FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(fb, new FirefoxProfile());
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get(ADDRESS_TO_TEST);

    }

    @Test(priority=0)
    public void testLoginPageAppear() {

        // Create Login Page object
        Login = new Main(driver);

        // Verify login page title
        /*
         * String pageTitle = Login.pageTittle();
         * Assert.assertTrue(pageTitle.toLowerCase().contains(
         * "Sign in to continue to Gmail"));
         */

        System.out.println("Login-->" + Login);
        Login.loginToGmail("abc@gmail.com", "2013");

        homePage = new HomePage(driver);
        // Verify home page

        Assert.assertTrue(homePage.getHOmePageEmailAddress().toLowerCase()
                .contains("Google Account: abc@gmail.com"));

    }

}
```

**POM.xml:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>GmailLogin</groupId>
  <artifactId>GmailLogin</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <dependencies>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
          <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
          <version>2.45.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
          <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
          <version>6.8.5</version>
      </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19</version>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>          
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

Comment: Can u share pom.xml file ?

Comment: @mk08 I have edited question with pom please check.

Comment: You may want to add HTTP component dependency as below. `<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1</version>
    </dependency>`

Comment: @mk08 Thanks for replying but with this dependency I still get the same error. Actually the problem is that when I execute the code it opens the old version browser as per my configuration. So, its not opening the older version of firefox  like 15 or 18. It opens only latest version of firefox and that time I don't get that error.

Comment: You mean with maven, it is not opening the older versions? and when you execute (with what) it takes your setting in code. Sorry I have not faced this issue till now. Thought of commenting only for the maven dependency. :)

Comment: @mk08 Exactly with maven its not opening the older versions at the time of execution of the code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93172/discussion-between-user1989314-and-mk08).